# Moving through an array one by one on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I have an interaction that populates/repopulates a modal on click. Population happens through a traversal of key values of a JSON object.  I need to have a bit of logic that sets these keys' index (back or forth) depending on the users clicks.

The arrows in the top right corner(`.next` `.prev`) are what trigger the back and forth traversal.  `Unique post` are where the JSON data will be updated.

I've put comments inside the code and a [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/4gfmu/1/) for ease of reading.  I really need the traversal to have a bit of validation for when it hits the end of the array to go to start and vice versa.  I must abide by the `next` and `prev` button constraints because they are the triggers that synchronizes multiple interactions I've made prior to.

CODE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4gfmu/1/)

```
   /*
SAMPLE OF DATA
===============
var data = {
    created_at: "2013-07-15T05:58:25Z",
    id: 21,
    name: "Skatelocal.ly",
    svg :  "<svg> ... </svg>",
    post_a :  "This is an awesome post 1",
    post_b :  "This is an awesome post 2",
    post_c :  "this is an awesome post 3",
    post_d :  "this is an awesome post 4"
};
*/
postInModal = function(data, status) {
      var keys;
      keys = ["post_a", "post_b", "post_c", "post_d"];
      return $.each(keys, function(i, key) {
        var val;
        val = data[key];

        $(".next").on({
          click: function() {
          //if val is on last index
              //reset val
              return $(".unique-post").hide().html(val).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to first val index
            //else  
              //val++
              return $("unique-post").hide().html(val).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to next val index
          }
        });
        return $(".prev").on({
          click: function() {
            //if val is on index 0
              //reset val last index
              return $(".unique-post").hide().html(val).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to last val index
            //else  
              //val--
              return $(".unique-post").hide().html(val).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to previous val index

          }
        });
      });
    };
```

*The JSON data in the end will be a html markup.*
[image: unique post]

Comment: you are missing a `.` here `return $("unique-post")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, You need to go back and forth through an array.

```
var indexer = 0 //Start point

//NEXT:
if (indexer == key.length - 1){
    return $(".unique-post").hide().html(indexer).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to first val index
} else {
   indexer++
   return $("unique-post").hide().html(indexer).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to next val index
}

//PREV:
if (indexer == 0){
    return $(".unique-post").hide().html(indexer).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to first val index
} else {
   indexer--
   return $("unique-post").hide().html(indexer).fadeIn(); //sets .modal-main to next val index
}
```

I feel like it is as simple as that, but let me know if doesn't work or fit with what you are trying to accomplish.

V/R

Comment: trying it out now.  I'm going to try to pop this in my next prev methods. 2 mins

Comment: Wasn't 100% what I was going for but it lead me to the correct answer thanks man.